# unable to divide two columns with same name from different tables with count and distinct filter

Tags: mysql, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I do have one table with 2 columns and another with 2 columns

employee(id, transaction_date),
employee_1(id, transaction_date)

Below is the query i tried, but it's returning an error

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) / COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM employee, employee_1
```

Error is

```
SQL Error [2028] [42601]: SQL compilation error:
ambiguous column name 'id'
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT employee.id) / COUNT(DISTINCT employee_1.id) FROM employee, employee_1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From performance perspective using `CROSS JOIN` is suboptimal. This pattern is called [“Exploding” Joins](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-query-profile.html#exploding-joins):

> One of the common mistakes SQL users make is joining tables without providing a join condition (resulting in a “Cartesian product”), or providing a condition where records from one table match multiple records from another table. For such queries, the Join operator produces significantly (often by orders of magnitude) more tuples than it consumes.

A better approach is to use indepenedent queries and secure against division by zero:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM employee)
      / NULLIF((SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM employee_1),0)
```

or

```
SELECT DIV0((SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM employee),
            (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM employee_1));
```

Comment: Completely agree on performance cost of the join just to then distinct count. `DIV0` is another safe option  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/div0.html#div0

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the column reference unique. This is done with a table alias or the initial table name in front of the columnname: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/from.html

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT employee.id) / COUNT(DISTINCT employee_1.id) FROM employee, employee_1
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT emp.id) / COUNT(DISTINCT emp1.id) FROM employee emp, employee_1 emp1
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but it's taking too much time to run the query